# How can I programmatically fill out a remote form with data from another form using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Requirement: User fills out form A. Data from form A is then passed to form B on another site.

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything yet. Not sure where to begin (apart from the user submitting form A). I looked at scRubyt and nokogiri but I'm not sure which is better, if either are an option.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check out mechanize.
https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize

Say the site is `http://mysite.com`, and there's one field "name" that you want to fill in.

```
require 'mechanize'

def fill_out_form(name)

  # our agent
  agent = Mechanize.new

  # load mysite.com
  page = agent.get('http://mysite.com')

  # Fill out the form
  form = page.form_with(:name => 'name-form')
  form.name = name
  page = agent.submit(form)
end
```

then just call this from your controller

```
FormFiller.fill_out_form(params[:name])
```

---

I adapted this form the flickr example
https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/examples/flickr_upload.rb

Comment: just be aware it won't work (hopefuly!) if form B as mere security such as crsf...

Comment: @apneadiving, it should work. Mechanize keeps hold of cookies and sessions between requests, and actually submits the form with all the fields. Assuming the CSRF is implemented as a hidden field, then it will be passed along.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Looks like Mechanize is what I was looking for. However, is there anything I should be aware of if form B is on a site using SSL?

Comment: @genericuser I hope not. If Mechanize doesn't deal with that for you, its a bug.